# How to detect Windows alt-code input without relying on keypress?

Tags: javascript, windows, events, keyboard, event-handling

For those unfamiliar with [Windows alt-codes](https://www.alt-codes.net/), on Windows if you press <kbd>Alt+0222</kbd> for example, you'll get the character `Þ`.

Is there any way to detect the insertion of these characters without relying on the [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event) `keypress` event?

Comment: Try oninput handler: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput